# Localized Strings only applying translations through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring, swift5

I have created the strings files for a few languages and added texts to them. The spanish file, for example, is called **Main.strings (Spanish)** and I have added two texts to it. The first one to apply the translation to a label in the interface builder (it works) and the other one to print in the viewdidload method (it doesn't work).

```
"yFi-2X-1s7.text" = "hola";
"lb-hello" = "hola";
```

What I mean with "it doesn't work" is that the text that is being printed is **lb-hello** instead of **hola**

This is the code I'm using to print the text:

```
NSLog(NSLocalizedString("lb-hello", comment: "Hello translated"));
```

Any idea about why the translation only works through the Interface Builder? Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you have in your String file "Hola" key ? "lb-hello" or "yFi-2X-1s7.text" ?

Comment: I created both, yFi-2X-1s7.text to try the translation with the interface builder and the other one with the lb-hello to do it through the code

Comment: What is the name of your string file ? and please edit your question and add both key value for two example you have.

Comment: just edited the whole question @andesta.erfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer to my own question.

Apparently, **if the strings file is called Main.strings (Spanish)** it works to localize label IDs but not to create new variables and apply them through code.

To do be able to create new ones and use them in the code, you have to rename each file and replace Main for Localizable. So **the file name for Spanish has to be Localizable.strings (Spanish)**

Comment: All the time the string file should be named Localizable.strings so compiler can found the file and parse it.